# Format a string to display only 3 last characters and others as asterisks in RDLC

Tags: rdlc, report-viewer2012

I have a requirement where I need to display account number in RDLC such that it displays last 3 characters and all other characters are displayed as '*'. for eg 1234567 needs to be displayed as ****567. I'm passing in dataset containing account number to the RDLC and need to write an expression which will format account number to display 3 last digits and all preceding characters as"*". Can anyone help me with the expression writing for it? I'm very new to writing expression on RDLC.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewMyers: sorry if my question isn't to the point, I have edited the question. I need help with expression that will be needed to display only 3 last digits of account number and hide other digits with *. help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.... I wrote code to format account no with asterisks and called the method in RDLC expression.